# how to use Gradle's configure on demand feature in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In an effort to speed up my gradle builds on a large project i have executed this on the command line:

```
./gradlew aFreeDebug --profile --configure-on-demand
```

and i checked the report is in /build/reports/profile and the speed was incredibly faster based on the report.

Now i would like android studio to use the [configure on demand feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). When i build and install the apk using android studio it seems its not using configure on demand feature (which i know is a incubating feature but i'll take the risk).

one way i thought about doing this is creating a gradle.properties file in ~/.gradle directory.  but im not sure if android studio will see it. Who can confirm.  Right now in the  ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file i have the following set:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

this runs the daemon right away so its faster but im not even sure if android studio picks this up and i'd like to add the configure on demand feature in here as well but i wish i could just do it in android studio perhaps with a gradle parameters section.  Is there anyway ?  Also should my changes be in gradle wrapper since android studio is using the wrapper ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out where to add this. there is a checkbox for it in android studio already.

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Compiler -> Gradle -> Command-line Options

[image]